# Webots R2019a revision 1 Crashed in Python API

Tags: python, webots

I try to get the depth image of a Kinect camera using Python. The webots can detect Kinect device successfully and can enable it too. but, when I try to use getRangeImage function to get the depth values, the controller is crashed.
My code is as follows:

```
self.kinectrange=self.getRangeFinder("kinect range")
self.kinectrange.enable(timestep)
image=self.kinectrange.getRangeImage ()
```

What is the problem?
O.S : windows 10
Webots: R2019a revision 1

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to reproduce the problem on R2019a revision 1, I tested with this controller (inspired from your code): https://gist.github.com/DavidMansolino/b95442478c4195dc72022b058758fbf6
This controller prints 'None' which is to be expected since a 'robot.step(timestep)' is expected between the call to 'kinectrange.enable' and 'kinectrange.getRangeImage'. Your controller is probably crashing because you are trying to process this None image.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I checked the following code in my controller: image=self.kinectrange.getRangeImage()
print(image)                                                                                                                   the output image is not null but after adding the following code the controller still crashed :                                                                                                             kinectvalue=self.kinectrange.rangeImageGetDepth(image,320 , 5, 5)

Comment: Did you try to add the step after enabling the range finder (https://gist.github.com/DavidMansolino/b95442478c4195dc72022b058758fbf6#file-my_controller-py-L9) ?

Comment: Yes, I also checked other conditions , I added another step before using rangeImageGetDepth function:                                                                                                
 robot.kinectrange = robot.getRangeFinder("kinect range")
robot.kinectrange.enable(timestep)
robot.step(timestep) 
image = robot.kinectrange.getRangeImage()
robot.step(timestep)
kinectvalue=robot.kinectrange.rangeImageGetDepth(image,200 , 5, 5)
print(kinectvalue)  the print showed a value but controller still crashed.before, getRangeImage command had problem and now rangeImageGetDepth

Comment: Can you post (maybe on https://gist.github.com/) the complete code of your controller with the step?

Comment: I used your code which attached above -->(gist.github.com/DavidMansolino/…), and yes, as you said, your code does not have any problem. but I added another line to the end of this code as below:            kinectvalue=robot.kinectrange.rangeImageGetDepth(image,320, 5, 5)           using this line makes the controller crashed.

Comment: The complete code of my controller: 
https://gist.github.com/ft2019/4a00307a63626005c40f70eeab20ec4d

Comment: Dear David, I'm still waiting for your answer. Thanks

Comment: I am sorry for the late answer, I didn't saw the notification about your message until now. I checked your example and everything is working fine: https://i.ibb.co/QNP9qkZ/Capture-du-2019-04-15-08-44-48.png Are you sure you are using the latest version of Webots?

Comment: I checked the version of the used Webots, it was 2019a revision1. I do not find the problem. here I uploaded my project entirely: https://github.com/ft2019/Kinect_Webots. Could you please use my project to see the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry, but once again I tried your example and it is working fine, please see: https://i.ibb.co/G2yGGnr/Capture-du-2019-04-16-09-09-03.png
Maybe you should try to use a different version of Python.

Comment: I did another test and I could find the problem. If the controller tries to execute the highlighted instruction in image:https://github.com/ft2019/Kinect_Webots/blob/ErrorImage/Capture.PNG  for the same i and j value, it will crash!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention. I use python 3.7.1. Could you please let me know which version of python you use?

Comment: I tried python 2.7.9,  2.7.13,  2.7.16,  3.6,  and 3.7.1. But the problem still exists. The following error has been occurred using python 2.7.9:                                     kinectvalue=self.kinectrange.rangeImageGetDepth(image,320 , i, j)
[ctrlKinect] TypeError: in method 'Camera_rangeImageGetValue', argument 2 of type 'PyList' of 'PyFloat' WARNING: 'ctrlKinect' controller crashed.

Comment: Dear David, Could you please let me know which version of python you use?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.12, but this should work with any version of Python 2.7.x, 3.5.x, 3.6.x and 3.7.x

Comment: https://github.com/ft2019/Kinect_Webots/blob/master/controllers/ctrlKinect/ctrlKinect.py